# Receiving search results with grouping by doc type in one call (NEST, AWS Elasticsearch)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nest, aws-elasticsearch

all. Thanks in advance for your help!

I'm requesting paged data from AWS Elasticsearch using NEST. Each document in AWS Elasticsearch index has a content type (Topic, Question and Video). In response I receive a list of documents for the current page and their total results. Everything is ok with it.

So the question is: how can I receive some kind of response map as well as search results in one call?

I mean, for example, here is my response:
Doc 1 - Topic
Doc 2 - Topic
Doc 3 - Video
Doc 4 - Question 
Doc 5 - Video
Total results: 5 items.

In addition to this, I'd like to receive the following 'map':
Topic - 2 items
Video - 2 items
Question - 1 item

Is it possible to do in one request? Or how this can be done by several requests? Maybe NEST Aggregations is something of the needed solution, but it seems that do not have 'count' logic

This is the search request for paged data and some models:

```cs
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId  { get; set; }
    public ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public virtual DocumentSearchResponse FullTextSearch(DocumentSearchParams searchParams)
{
    var resultsSearchRequest = _elasticClient.Search<Document>(s => s.Index("some_index")
                                            .Query(q => q.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.DocumentId).Value(searchParams.ContentId))
                                                     && q.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.ContentType).Terms(searchParams.GetContentTypesIds()))
                                                     && q.MultiMatch(m => m.Fields(fs => fs.Field(f => f.Title).Field(f => f.Description))
                                                         .Query(searchParams.SearchValue)
                                                         .Type(TextQueryType.MostFields)))
                                            .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(f => f.UpdatedOn))
                                            .From((searchParams.PageNumber - 1) * searchParams.PageSize)
                                            .Size(searchParams.PageSize));

    // Is valid check
    return new DocumentSearchResponse
    {
        PageResults = _searchResponseHelper.ToPageResults(resultsSearchRequest.Documents),
        PageResultsMap = new Dictionary<ContentType, int>, // <- here
        TotalResultsCount = resultsSearchRequest.HitsMetadata.Total.Value
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found it out. Maybe, someone will find it helpful. 
The thing I've needed are 'Aggregations'. Adding the following row before .Form and .Size will group the search results by the specified field:

```cs
.Aggregations(a => a.Terms("contentType", t => t.Field(f => f.ContentType)))
.Query(...)
.Form(...)
.Size(...)
```

To process the result to the Dictionary I need, add the following (
`searchAggregations` is `searchResponse.Aggregations`):

```cs
public Dictionary<ContentType, long> ToPageResultsMap(AggregateDictionary searchAggregations)
{
    var pageResultsMap = new Dictionary<ContentType, long>();

    var buckets = searchAggregations.Terms(DataConsts.SearchContentTypeDocFieldName).Buckets;

    foreach (var item in buckets)
    {
        if(int.TryParse(item.Key, out int contentType))
        {
            pageResultsMap.Add((ContentType)contentType, item.DocCount.HasValue ? item.DocCount.Value : 0);
        }
    }

    return pageResultsMap;
}
```